# In PHP, check if a file can be deleted

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I have a large video file that is streamed using a streaming server outside my control, and sometimes I want to delete the video file. When the file happens to be viewed by someone using the streaming server, PHP errors with "Permission denied".

I would like to check before attempting to delete if the file can be deleted or not. I do not want to actually try to delete the file and see if that fails, I would like to check beforehand.

This is my code so far:

```
$file = "video.flv";
$file2 = "newvideoname.flv";
clearstatcache();
if (is_writeable($file)) {
    echo "is writeable";
}
else {
    echo "is NOT writeable";
}
echo "\n";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a+');
if (!flock($fh, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    // file locked, do something else
    echo "is locked";
}
else {
    echo "not locked!";
}
fclose($fh);
echo "\n";
if (touch($file)) {
    echo "modification time has been changed to present time";
}
else {
    echo "Sorry, could not change modification time";
}
echo "\n";
rename($file, $file2);
```

The output I get when I stream video.flv while executing the code:

```
is writeable
not locked!
modification time has been changed to present time
PHP Warning:  rename(video.flv,newvideoname.flv): Permission denied in ...
```

Sometimes I get:

```
is writeable
PHP Warning:  fopen(video.flv): failed to open stream: Permission denied ...
PHP Warning:  flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
is locked
PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
PHP Warning:  touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied
Sorry, could not change modification time
PHP Warning:  rename(video.flv,newvideoname.flv): Permission denied ...
```

So sometimes the file cannot be locked by PHP and it cannot be touch()ed by PHP, and then of course the rename doesn't work, but sometimes PHP says "all is fine" until the rename command. The rename command has *never* worked by random chance.

What should I do with the file?

Comment: @KA_lin not the issue, when the video is not being streamed, the rename command works perfectly

Comment: @KA_lin the issue would be not about file permissions

Comment: What Operating System are you running this on?

Comment: @JRSofty it's windows 2008 server edition

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!flock(fopen($file, 'a+'), LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
```

You are locking the file. Make sure you unlock it again if the call succeeds (just after `echo "not locked!";`

Comment: You have closed the file, have you also unlocked it?

Comment: straight from the php manual: "The lock is released also by fclose() (which is also called automatically when script finished)."

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it is that when you checked if the file is locked with `flock` you opened a resource to the file but did not close the file. So the file is now locked and you can't rename it.

Comment: I think this is the reason actually

Comment: @Tominator did you also close the file using `fclose()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a file that is streaming...if you REALLY WANT TO...make a copy, raname it, and put the file(original) in a stack(DB) and have a cron job or something to delete it...

Comment: not the issue, when the video is not being streamed, the rename command works perfectly

Comment: So even if you get the message "not locked" you still can`t rename?

Comment: Indeed, even with the message "not locked" and the current code sample, I cannot rename/delete. The rename happens after the fclose, so putting it in the else branch doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is here :

```
$file = "test.pdf";

if (!is_file($file)) {
    print "File doesn't exist.";
} else {
    $fh = @fopen($file, "r+");
    if ($fh) {
        print "File is not opened and seems able to be deleted.";
        fclose($fh);
    } else {
        print "File seems to be opened somewhere and can't be deleted.";
    }
}
```