# PHP: Check whether file can be deleted

Tags: php

I would like to know whether I can delete a file.

The function `is_writable()` does not work because it does not check whether the containing directory allows deletion of files.

I also cannot to use `@unlink()` because I first generate a list of deletable files and delete only a portion of them after doing some calculations.

The answers in this question also do not check whether the directory allows deletion of files: [In PHP, check if a file can be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900936/in-php-check-if-a-file-can-be-deleted) - so it seems that this simple question has not yet been answered, even after so many years.

Comment: `is_writable` on the directory is the only necessary permission you need to have to delete a file according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original answer by Striezel in 2018 has 1 missing if clause parentheses. The code should read:

```
if (is_writable(dirname("/path/to/the/file.ext")))
{
    echo "File is deletable.";
}
else
{
    echo "File cannot be deleted.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the omission. I've adjusted my answer and added the missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

As @apokryfos pointed out in comment, you [need to have write permission on the file's parent directory to delete a file within that directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files). Using that information a check could look like this:

```
if (is_writable(dirname("/path/to/the/file.ext")))
{
    echo "File is deletable.";
}
else
{
    echo "File cannot be deleted.";
}
```

The [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function gets the directory the file is located in. Then we can use [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) to check whether we have write permission on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileperms to find out what the directory permissions are.

```
echo substr (sprintf ('% o', fileperms ('/ tmp')), -4);
```

And then use is_writable() to check the files.